# Laravel how to extract inner collection data to parent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following Models:
User have employees, and employee is type of person.
If i try to get the user employees and the person data of the employees
int the controller i type:
auth()->user()->employees()->with('self')->get()
Example:
User Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class, 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

Employee Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function self()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id', 'person_id');
    }

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Person Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```
[
{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "per_day",
        "description": null,
        "salary": "7082.00",
        "self": {
            "name": "Ali",
            "phone": "0523037298",
            "email": "schaefer.dayton@hotmail.com"
        }
    }
]
```

i want to extract the data from self to parent like:

```
[
{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "per_day",
        "description": null,
        "salary": "7082.00",
        "name": "Ali",
        "phone": "0523037298",
        "email": "schaefer.dayton@hotmail.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: Post the code as how you're retrieving this collection

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: That's not the code responsible for the response, add the route or controller or resource code

Comment: return auth()->user()->employees()->with('self')->get() ;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the merge method of the Collections you get back from the Eloquent query. Something like this:

```
$user->merge($user->self)->all()
```

You might have to play around with it a bit, so here's the documentation for the method:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-merge